# Clad usage - for old dress

Tags: word-usage

I learned that clad can mean dressed, but I'm not sure the exact usage of it.

Normally I used to say

```
1. An old man, dressed up in old clothing, is standing there.
2. He dressed up well/neat
3. He dressed up in old clothing.
```

Can I use "clad" in all these sentences instead of "dressed up" like below?

```
1. An old man, clad in old clothing, is standing there.
2. He clad well/neat
3. He clad in old clothing.
```

I don't think clad fits well in all of these sentences. May be it fits well only in the first sentence. It doesn't fit in 2nd and 3rd sentences I guess. Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct. They might work with "is clad", though.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung You mean "He is clad well" works?

Comment: @T2E You are correct, only the first of your three examples works. *Why* that's the case fabulously represents just how convoluted this language really is. I'm hoping somebody comes along and explains it soon, because I kind of *know*, and it's making *my* head spin. In order to properly address it, I'd have to look up several terms I haven't used in 30 years.

Comment: It's not something I'd say, but it seems grammatically valid. Conversely, [this is the only place on the whole internet where "he clad well" appears without some kind of "is" verb.](https://www.google.com/search?q="he+clad+well")

Comment: @T2E "He is clad well" is grammatically correct, but sounds terrible.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Yes, seems valid grammatically. Doesn't sound good. I'm wondering is this really grammatically valid or is there any strange rule to say this invalid grammatically. I don't understand why it's sound terrible. It's just because of no one ever used it? Why didn't they?

Comment: @T2E I'm sure of it. That usage is correct. Please don't make me explain predicate adjectives and transitives and *stuff* :)  One of the reasons that "He is clad well" sounds so awful is that "clad" is a word that *nobody* uses. Except on Cooking.SE - Then it's AllClad, a brand of cookware.

Comment: "Clad" is just an old, odd word in general. It has somehow survived this long beside its synonym "clothed" (which is more obvious in its need for an existence verb because it looks past-tense to the modern eye), but isn't likely to be found in common speech or writing unless someone is [putting on airs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_on_airs).

Comment: Incidentally, if the first three examples are meant to describe the same situation (the man is currently "dressed up"), 2 and 3 will each need an "is" as well.

Comment: Weird word though, because as *archaic* as it is, an average native speaking third-grader could probably define it.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Hey! With your last comment you made the point I was working on in the answer I don't want to write! It's kismet, man! You do it!

Comment: @Jolenealaska It's where "clothed" comes from in the first place, via cláðde ("klath-deh") and it probably shows up in more children's stories than I can readily remember, but I agree that that is strange. I _shan't_ be writing an answer, because I don't know _wherefore_ any of this is the way that it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Clad* is a fossil, an archaic past and past participle form of the verb *clothe*, now generally replaced by *clothed*, and having the same sense.

Unlike *dress*, which may be used both transitively and intransitively, *clothe* may be used only as transitive verb: it requires a direct object, the person who is clothed.

Consequently, your first example, “an old man clad in old clothing”, is grammatical—here *clad* is the past participle, employed as an adjective. But your other examples are not grammatical. You must provide a direct object:

> He clad **himself** well/neatly.
>   He clad **himself** in old clothing.

*Clad* as a participle is a strictly literary form. It is almost never heard in conversation, and is old-fashioned even in writing.

*Clad* as a finite verb is distinctly archaic; it should be used only if you are trying to sound mediaeval.<sup>†</sup>

I advise you not to use either; use *clothed* instead, in formal contexts, or *dressed* in either formal or informal contexts.

Do not, however, use *dress **up*** as you do in your examples. This is used in only two senses:

> To dress in more formal attire than usual: *She always dresses up to go to the theatre.*
>   With *as*, to disguise oneself in clothing: *She dressed up as a Klingon for the costume party.*

---

<sup>†</sup>Since the matter has been raised in the comments, I may mention that *clad*, as both participle and finite verb, is much more widely known than it is used because it is a very popular word among historical novelists and writers of fantasy. For instance, the folk hero Robin Hood and his Merry Men are almost inevitably described as “clad in Kendal green”. (Not one reader in twenty knows what Kendal green is, but it doesn’t matter.)

Comment: Woo-Hoo! How did I know it was going to be you?!? +1  BTW, Kendall is a family first name :)

Comment: I would not accept "He clad himself neatly" to mean: He dressed neatly.  in contemporary English with perhaps an exception for poetic license. It is much more used as a past particle.

Comment: Lincoln green, surely?

Answer (score 0):

Well answered above. A couple of points on how it is more often used.

You are more likley to hear someone described as "He is well clad" than "He clad himself well" - it is neater and shorter.

More common is a technical use for e.g. the cladding of a building, or pipework, or whatever - a surface covering. But this usually leads to it being described as "cladded" rather than just "clad"